# pandas: groupby, add new column of unique occurances in one column with condition on a different column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've seen a lot of variants of this question on stack overflow but none of them seem to work for this specific case.

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a'],
'col2': [1,2,1,4,5,6,6,6,9,1],
'col3': ['LOW', 'HIGH', 'LOW','LOW','HIGH', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'HIGH']
})
```

I now want to add two new columns, `low-count` and `high-count`, to this dataframe. For each value of `col1`, `low-count` is the number of unique values in `col2` when `col3=='LOW'`, and `high-count` is the number of unique values in `col2` when `col3=='HIGH'`.

So resulting dataframe would be:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a'],
    'col2': [1,2,1,4,5,6,6,6,9,1],
    'col3': ['LOW', 'HIGH', 'LOW','LOW','HIGH', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'HIGH'],
    'low-count': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'high-count': [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    })
```

because, for example, for value `b` in `col1`, there are 2 unique values of `col2` when `col3=='LOW'`, hence the `low-count` for all rows where `col1=='b'`, we'll have `low-count` to be 2.

I've tried the following with `groupby` and `apply`, but I can't figure out how to add it as a new column to the original dataframe:

`df.groubpy('col1').apply(lambda x: x[x['col3']=='LOW']['col2'].unique()`

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Shouldn't `c` have `2` as a *low-count* ? Seems like a typo in your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do so, but a simple way is to calculate low_count and high_count separately and then merge to the original dataframe:

```
df_low = df[df['col3'] == 'LOW'].groupby(['col1'], as_index=False).agg(low_count = ('col2', 'count'))
df_high = df[df['col3'] == 'HIGH'].groupby(['col1'], as_index=False).agg(high_count = ('col2', 'count'))

df = df.merge(df_low, on='col1', how='left')
df = df.merge(df_high, on='col1', how='left')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3  low_count  high_count
0    a     1   LOW          1           2
1    a     2  HIGH          1           2
2    b     1   LOW          2           1
3    b     4   LOW          2           1
4    b     5  HIGH          2           1
5    c     6   LOW          2           2
6    c     6  HIGH          2           2
7    c     6   LOW          2           2
8    c     9  HIGH          2           2
9    a     1  HIGH          1           2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), of the *low-high* counts, to place it at the right of your `df` :

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index="col1", columns="col3", values="col2",
            aggfunc="count", sort=False).add_suffix("-COUNT")

out = df.merge(piv, left_on="col1", right_index=True, how="left")
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  col1  col2  col3  LOW-COUNT  HIGH-COUNT
0    a     1   LOW          1           2
1    a     2  HIGH          1           2
2    b     1   LOW          2           1
3    b     4   LOW          2           1
4    b     5  HIGH          2           1
5    c     6   LOW          2           2
6    c     6  HIGH          2           2
7    c     6   LOW          2           2
8    c     9  HIGH          2           2
9    a     1  HIGH          1           2

[10 rows x 5 columns]
```